# SQL/BigQuery how can I sessionize this data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm struggling to figure out how to write a query that will properly aggregate the below sample data. This sample data represents the output of an aggregate query that I then need to filter down further. I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think I need to sessionize this data, where the session starts on the first row of a `resource_name` that is `null` for `complete` and ends when that resource name has `true` in column `complete`, with a lag time of ~ 30 minutes.

I unfortunately don't have the ability to change the data, and all of the output below is from a single table with a query that aggregates the fields as such.

Example Data:

```
|resource_name|operation_type|initiate|complete|timestamp             |
|-------------|--------------|--------|--------|----------------------|
|foo          |full          |true    |null    |2021-11-01-5:51:46 UTC|
|foo          |full          |null    |true    |2021-11-01-5:51:49 UTC|
|foo          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:02:22 UTC|  <--- foo begins
|foo          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:02:37 UTC|
|foo          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:03:19 UTC|
|baz          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:03:25 UTC|
|baz          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:03:29 UTC|
|foo          |full          |true    |null    |2021-11-01-7:03:31 UTC|
|foo          |full          |null    |true    |2021-11-01-7:12:55 UTC|  <--- foo ends
|bar          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:39:22 UTC|  <--- bar starts
|bar          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:40:37 UTC|
|baz          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:41:37 UTC|
|baz          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:41:39 UTC|
|baz          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:41:45 UTC|
|bar          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:44:19 UTC|
|bar          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-7:44:58 UTC|
|bar          |full          |true    |null    |2021-11-01-7:45:31 UTC|
|bar          |full          |null    |true    |2021-11-01-7:47:55 UTC|  <--- bar ends
|bar          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-9:38:22 UTC|  <--- bar starts again 
|bar          |incomplete    |null    |null    |2021-11-01-9:40:37 UTC|
|bar          |full          |true    |null    |2021-11-01-9:45:31 UTC|
|bar          |full          |null    |true    |2021-11-01-9:51:55 UTC|  <--- bar ends again
```

What I'm trying to do is find the timestamp differences for each `resource_name` between the first `incomplete` `operation_type` and the next `full` `operation_type` where `complete = true`, for each resource_name.

So, in this case, I would return one value for `foo`, and two values for `bar`. `foo` has one initial `incomplete` `operation_type`, and one `full` `operation_type` with `complete = true`, and `bar` has two instances of the same.

My results should be (duration not computed so you can see timestamps that should be picked up, sorted DESC):

```
|resource_name|duration                                                        |
|-------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|bar          | timestamp_diff(2021-11-01-9:51:55 - 2021-11-01-9:38:22, SECOND)|
|foo          | timestamp_diff(2021-11-01-7:12:55 - 2021-11-01-7:02:22, SECOND)|
|bar          | timestamp_diff(2021-11-01-7:47:55 - 2021-11-01-7:39:22, SECOND)|
```

Comment: You need to show us your current query and all relevant `CREATE TABLE` definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided I have come with this solution:

I follow these steps to recreate it on my side:

1. create a .csv table based on the data you provide in your post.
2. created a dataset and a table
3. filled the table with the .csv file
4. run below query.

So, the approach should be about getting your success runs grouped. From that point you just need to make sure that the incomplete time values you retrieve needs to be consider when you calculate the differentiation.

**CSV**

```
foo,full,true,,2021-11-01 05:51:46
foo,full,,true,2021-11-01 05:51:49
foo,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:02:22
foo,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:02:37
foo,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:03:19
baz,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:03:25
baz,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:03:29
foo,full,true,,2021-11-01 07:03:31
foo,full,,true,2021-11-01 07:12:55
bar,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:39:22
bar,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:40:37
baz,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:41:37
baz,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:41:39
baz,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:41:45
bar,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:44:19
bar,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 07:44:58
bar,full,true,,2021-11-01 07:45:31
bar,full,,true,2021-11-01 07:47:55
bar,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 09:38:22
bar,incomplete,,,2021-11-01 09:40:37
bar,full,true,,2021-11-01 09:45:31
bar,full,,true,2021-11-01 09:51:55
```

**Bigquery Code**

```
with operations_success as (
    select resource_name,
    operation_type,
    timestamp,
    row_number() over(partition by resource_name) as occurrence
    from <MY BIGQUERY TABLE>  
    where operation_type = 'full' and complete = True
)
select resource_name,duration
from (
    select s.resource_name
    ,t.occurrence 
    ,t.timestamp as success_time
    ,date_diff(t.timestamp,case when t.occurrence = 1 then MIN(s.timestamp) 
                                    else (select MIN(x.timestamp) from <MY BIGQUERY TABLE> x 
                                    left join operations_success xs on x.resource_name = xs.resource_name and occurrence = t.occurrence-1
                                    where x.resource_name = s.resource_name and x.timestamp > xs.timestamp
                                    and x.operation_type = 'incomplete') end
    , SECOND) as duration
    from <MY BIGQUERY TABLE> s 
    inner join operations_success t on s.resource_name = t.resource_name
    where s.operation_type = 'incomplete'
    group by s.resource_name,t.occurrence,t.timestamp
) as resource_log
where duration > 0
order by success_time
```

**Update 05/11/2021**: I have updated the code and the though process to reflect latest comment.

output will be:

```
1| foo | 633
2| bar | 513
3| bar | 813
```

Please let me know if this code help you in your process.

Regards,

Comment: This is very helpful. How would you handle it if the hours rolled over? For example, 9:59 to 10:03?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my response. The issue you mention is no longer present.

Comment: Thank you @Betjens, this was a great learning experience. I had to extrapolate this out to fit my actual production data, but your example was perfect and made it all click for me. Much appreciated!